# AVPlayerController with custom control not working in iOS 11

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton, avplayer, ios11

I am using an `AVPlayerViewController` to play my local video file.

I also added custom **skip button** to skip video.

I have added this as **subview of AVPlayerViewController's View**.

It is working fine till iOS 10.3.3, but only not working in iOS 11.

My code:

```
 [self addChildViewController:avcontroller];
    [avcontroller.view addSubview:_skip];
    [avcontroller.view bringSubviewToFront:_skip];
    [self.view addSubview:avcontroller.view];
```

Help me!

**Thanks for your time**

Comment: maybe you should elaborate on what does it mean that it's not working.. is it crashing? or is everything looking as intended, it just does not skip the video? or is it rendered wrong?

Comment: I'm facing same issue . Still not found solution . It's completely working below iOS 11.